# How to keep asking user to input until condition is satisfied in C?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, user-input

This is small C program and I am trying to validate the user input. I want user to enter 3 values. Condition is that all 3 inputs should not be of same value. So how to loop the user input until condition is satisfied(True). Here is the code. Help me out, I am new to Programming, Thanks. :)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int u1,u2,u3;
    
    printf("Enter 3 Numbers : ");  //Printing
    scanf("%d %d %d",&u1,&u2,&u3); //Asking for Input
    
    if(u1==u2 || u2==u3 || u3==u1)       //This is the condition
    {
        printf("Condition is not Satisfied !");      
    }
}
```

So how do I loop it. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int u1,u2,u3;

    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(true)
    {
        printf( "Enter 3 Numbers: " );
        scanf( "%d %d %d", &u1, &u2, &u3 );

        if ( u1!=u2 && u2!=u3 && u3!=u1 )
            break;

        printf( "Error: Condition is not satisfied!\n" );
    }
}
```

In contrast to one of the other answers, this solution has the advantage that it only checks the condition once per loop iteration.

However, the above code (and the code of most other answers) has a serious issue: If the user enters an alphabetical letter instead of a number, the program will get stuck in an infinite loop. This is because it is not safe to call `scanf` without checking the return value.  See the following page for more information on why it is unsafe: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Therefore, it would be better to check the return value of `scanf` and to consume all characters on the remainder of the line. Consuming all leftover characters is important, because otherwise, if the user enters `6abc`, then `scanf` will consume the `6`, but leave `abc` on the input stream, so that the next time `scanf` is called (which will be in the next loop iteration), it will attempt to match `abc` and fail immediately without waiting for further input. This would cause an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int u1,u2,u3;
    int ret;

    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(true)
    {
        printf( "Enter 3 Numbers: " );
        if ( ( ret = scanf( "%d %d %d", &u1, &u2, &u3 ) ) != 3 )
        {
            int c;

            //check for unrecoverable error
            if ( ret == EOF )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable input error!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //print error message for recoverable error
            printf( "Unable to convert input!\n" );

            //consume all leftover characters on the line
            do
            {
                c = getchar();

            } while ( c != EOF && c != '\n' );
        }

        if ( u1!=u2 && u2!=u3 && u3!=u1 )
            break;

        printf( "Error: Condition is not satisfied!\n" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int u1,u2,u3;
    
    while(u1==u2 || u2==u3 || u3==u1)  //This is the condition
    {
        printf("Enter 3 Numbers : ");  //Printing
        scanf("%d %d %d",&u1,&u2,&u3); //Asking for Input
        
        if(u1==u2 || u2==u3 || u3==u1) 
            printf("Condition is not Satisfied !\n");    
        else
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems unnecessarily cumbersome to check for the exact same condition twice per loop iteration. See my answer for an alternative which only checks for the condition once.

Comment: Besides cumbersome, this answer is plainly wrong, since it has Undefined Behavior. Running this code on https://www.onlinegdb.com/ will demonstrate that the compiler optimized away all code and the program exits cleanly without doing anything.

Comment: @wovano: Yes, that is correct. It would have to be a `do`...`while` loop instead of a `while` loop, because otherwise, an uninitialized value is being read, which invokes undefined behavior.